# What's the most efficient way to find which elements of one array are close to any element in another?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

I have two 1-dimensional `numpy.ndarray` objects, and want to work out which elements in the first array are within `dx` of *any* element in the second.

What I have currently is

```py
# setup
numpy.random.seed(1)
a = numpy.random.random(1000)  # create one array
numpy.random.seed(2)
b = numpy.random.random(1000)  # create second array
dx = 1e-4  # close-ness parameter

# function I want to optimise
def find_all_close(a, b):
    # compare one number to all elements of b
    def _is_coincident(t):
        return (numpy.abs(b - t) <= dx).any()
    # vectorize and loop over a
    is_coincident = numpy.vectorize(_is_coincident)
    return is_coincident(a).nonzero()[0]
```

which returns a `timeit` result as follows

```
10 loops, best of 3: 16.5 msec per loop
```

What's the best way to optimise the `find_all_close` function, especially if `a` and `b` are guaranteed to be `float` arrays sorted in ascending order when they get passed to `find_all_close`, possibly with cython or similar?

In practice I'm working with arrays between 10,000 and 100,000 elements (or larger), and running this whole operation over a few hundred different `b` arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is for each element in the first array, do two binary searches the second array to find the element at most dx below and at most dx above the element in the first array.  This is linearithmic time:

```
left = np.searchsorted(b, a - dx, 'left')
right = np.searchsorted(b, a + dx, 'right')
a[left != right]
```

The linear algorithm has two pointers into the second array that keep track of a moving window as you iterate over elements in the first array.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is quadratic, here is a one pass linear time algorithm for sorted arrays. You just have to run in the two arrays at the right time.

```
def prox(a,b,dx):
    ia=ib=ir=0
    res=zeros(a.size,int32)
    while ia<a.size and ib<b.size:
        if abs(a[ia]-b[ib])<dx: 
            res[ir]=ia
            ir += 1
            ia += 1
        elif a[ia]>b[ib] :
               ib += 1
        else : ia += 1
    return res[:ir]
```

You can compile this code with Numba to further improve performance.

Test :

```
a=rand(1000)
b=rand(1000)
a.sort()
b.sort()

In [10]:   prox(a,b,1e-5)
Out[10]: 
array([ 35,  90, 159, 165, 174, 252, 276, 380, 383, 467, 508, 515, 641,
       658, 705, 711, 728, 814, 857, 871, 907, 945])

In [11]: %timeit prox(a,b,1e-4)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.23 ms per loop
In [12]: prox2=numba.jit(prox)
In [13]: %timeit prox2(a,b,1e-4)
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.1 µs per loop
```

Comment: Neither do I.That's life !

Answer (score 2):

This does not exploit the sorted nature of your data, so it does not have linear time complexity (although I suspect the runtime does benefit from it being sorted, cache-wise), but nlogn isnt bad, and it sure is hard to beat in terms of simplicity and well-testedness:

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
print(cKDTree(a[:, None]).query_ball_point(b[:, None], dx))
```

Answer (score 0):

When `a` and `b` are sorted arrays, this sorted nature could be *abused* with [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). The basic idea is that we get indices of `b` to the left of which each of the elements from `a` could be placed, such that the sorted order is maintained. This way we would know the right-side bound of the particular bin in `b`, where each of the elements from `a` could be placed. To get the left-side bound of the same bin, just subtract `1` from those indices found earlier. Then, get the differences between each `a` against the left and right bounds and see if either is within the threshold and if so, consider that as a valid index.

There would be some additional work for the corner cases, namely when elements in `a` are greater than the highest `b` and when elements are lesser than lowest `b`. If we work with `np.searchsorted`'s `'left'` search option, we just need to clip it at a minimum of `1` to find the right bounds, such that those same indices could be used across the entire array in one go. Thus, the implementation would look like this -

```
def find_all_close_searchsorted(a, b):
    lidx = np.searchsorted(b,a,'left').clip(min=1,max=b.size-1)
    close_mask = (np.abs(b[lidx] - a) <= dx) | (np.abs(b[lidx-1] - a) <= dx)
    return np.nonzero(close_mask)[0]
```

Runtime test -

```
In [2]: np.random.seed(1)
   ...: a = np.sort(np.random.random(1000))  # create one array
   ...: np.random.seed(2)
   ...: b = np.sort(np.random.random(1000))  # create second array
   ...: dx = 1e-4  # close-ness parameter
   ...: 

In [3]: np.allclose(find_all_close_searchsorted(a, b),find_all_close(a, b))
Out[3]: True

In [4]: %timeit find_all_close(a,b)
100 loops, best of 3: 16 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit find_all_close_searchsorted(a,b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 91.4 µs per loop
```

Comment: This is way too complicated. Why can't you just use searchsorted twice?

Comment: @NeilG Tried that, not sure if its straight forward with it either.

Comment: Should be simple.  Call searchsorted twice and then check if the left and right insertion points are different.  Maybe four lines of code.

Comment: @NeilG That would give you exact matches. How can you introduce the threshold `dx` into account?

Comment: search for the first elements minus `dx`, and search for the first elements plus `dx`.

Comment: @NeilG Made some edits to make it less complicated. I think it looks much better now :)

Comment: Still too complicated :)  See my answer.

Comment: @NeilG Beautiful, but slower because of double usage of `np.searchsorted` :)

Comment: It's still linearithmic.  If you want the fast algorithm, code the linear one :)